# javax.servlet.ServletException: WriteText method cannot write null text

Tags: jsf

I have created a Web application using *JSF+Icefaces+Richfaces+Primefaces*.It is working great while I run it from eclipse as a project but When I created its WAR file and deployed in GlassFish Server then while rendering a page it is throwing this exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: WriteText method cannot write null text
```

I searched but didn't get any good solution.A quick help is highly appreciated
**Edit:1**
I think this would be the relevant part for this

```
                        <li class="page_item" id="liMasterSearch">      <!-- this is for hide (<li class="page_item hide" id="liMasterSearch"> applied to every class) -->
                            <h:commandLink value="Search" action="#{masterRenderBean.showSimpleSearch}"></h:commandLink>
                        </li>

                        <li class="page_item" id="liAdvanceSearch">
                            <h:commandLink value="Advance Search" action="#{masterRenderBean.showADVS}"></h:commandLink>
                        </li>
```

Here you can see two links *(1)* Search **and** *(2)* Advance Search
when I click on Search , It shows search page (By rendering-Actually I have included all pages in masterpage and render them on commandlink functions)

```
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not masterRenderBean.simpleSearch}">
            <ui:include src="../../WebPages/SearchPages/MasterSearch.xhtml"></ui:include>
            </h:panelGroup>
```

But When I click on Advance Search link (on which this part should render)

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not masterRenderBean.advs}">  
        <ui:include src="../../WebPages/SearchPages/PersonalAdvanceSearch.xhtml"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

The browser show the above exception.
**NOTE:** Keep in mind that this problem is occurring in deploying.It is not coming in actual application when I run it from eclipse from code

**EDIT:2** I found in server logs that this exception is coming due to acefaces and this portion of code

```
<ace:autoCompleteEntry id="txtplaceofbirth"
                                      rows="10" autocomplete="false" 
                                        minChars="2" width="150" 
                                        value="#{inputPersonal.selectedplcofBirth}" 
                                        filterMatchMode="none"  
                                       valueChangeListener="#{inputPersonal.valueChangeEventCity}">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{inputPersonal.cities}"/>

                                        </ace:autoCompleteEntry></h:outputFormat>
```

is messing up.Any idea Why this is hapening?

**Edit #3:**
Here is the full tack trace of exception

```
[#|2012-11-19T09:55:48.026+0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=53;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.NullPointerException: WriteText method cannot write null text
    at org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter.writeText(DOMResponseWriter.java:314)
    at org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter.writeText(DOMResponseWriter.java:340)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutputMessageRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputMessageRenderer.java:163)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at org.icefaces.impl.renderkit.RendererWrapper.encodeChildren(RendererWrapper.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at org.icefaces.impl.renderkit.RendererWrapper.encodeChildren(RendererWrapper.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMPartialViewContext.processPartial(DOMPartialViewContext.java:142)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:981)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:391)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full stack trace. This will give us better insight in what is actually happening in the code until the exception is been thrown.

Comment: please check the updated answer .. I have pasted the full stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: WriteText method cannot write null text
    at org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter.writeText(DOMResponseWriter.java:314)
    at org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter.writeText(DOMResponseWriter.java:340)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutputMessageRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputMessageRenderer.java:163)
```

This is in first place caused by a bug in Mojarra. A `null` value of `<h:outputFormat>` isn't been dealt properly with. This has been reported as [issue 2351](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2351) which is been fixed since Mojarra 2.1.9.

Apparently the server in production is running an older version of Mojarra. You have 2 options:

1. Upgrade Mojarra version in production server. It's [currently](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) already at 2.1.14.
2. Make sure that no one of your `<h:outputFormat>` components ever receive a `null` value by conditionally rendering it only when the value is `not empty`.