# NullPointer Exception at org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter.writeText(DOMResponseWriter.java:314)

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish-3, icefaces-3

What can this exception mean exactly?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: WriteText method cannot write null text
  at org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter.writeText(DOMResponseWriter.java:314)
  at org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter.writeText(DOMResponseWriter.java:340)
```

this is only happening when deployed using icefaces autoCompleteEntry tag having **value** attribute set to backing bean property selectedplcofBirth defined as emptystring "".(i.e. private String selectedplcofBirth="";)

```
 <ace:autoCompleteEntry id="txtplaceofbirth"
                                      rows="10" autocomplete="false" 
                                        minChars="2" width="150" 
                                        value="#{inputPersonal.selectedplcofBirth}" 
                                        filterMatchMode="none"  
                                       valueChangeListener="#{inputPersonal.valueChangeEventCity}">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{inputPersonal.cities}"/>

                                        </ace:autoCompleteEntry></h:outputFormat>
```

Comment: why is being wrapped by `</h:outputFormat>` , try to remove the `</h:outputFormat>`

Comment: that was a failed effort to somehow apply css class which is not being applied directly in ace tag. Can this have some link to the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted the most important line of the stacktrace, the line thereafter:

```
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutputMessageRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputMessageRenderer.java:163)
```

*(see also this [exact duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410545/javax-servlet-servletexception-writetext-method-cannot-write-null-text/13452292#13452292) of your colleague or clone account)*

This exception occurs in older Mojarra versions when `<h:outputFormat>` is been used without `value` or `null` as `value`. E.g.

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{null}">...</h:outputFormat>
```

or

```
<h:outputFormat>...</h:outputFormat>
```

You should make sure that it is not `null`, or if the tag has no purpose at all, as confirmed by your comment on the question, just remove it altogether. Use a `<h:panelGroup>` instead. Or just learn CSS properly and fix your CSS selector.

Answer (score 0):

What specific version of ICEfaces are you using?  I was trying to line up the line numbers in the stack trace with a specific ICEfaces release to help troubleshoot.  If you are using an older version, it might be worth trying to upgrade.

Comment: i am using latest version of icefaces. The issue is solved it was due to <h:outputFormat> whcich after omission is now working fine as pointed out by BalusC